# How to rename WPF window file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is it possible to rename WPF Window in Visual Studio Community? Doing it breaks entire project, because it seems old name is used in some other places, and its very hard to track them down. The only method I'm aware of is removing old window, and creating new one, while moving code from previous window. But maybe there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It breaks, because, most probably, you aren't renaming also code-behind class.

To do so, you need to rename class in `Window.xaml.cs`.

So, right click on that class (should be `Window`) and rename appropriately. Also, rename the file as well.

Also, make sure that in XAML you refer to correct class after renaming.

So to break it down:

1. Rename XAML file.
2. Make sure that code-behind file and class are renamed appropriately.
3. Make sure to apply that change in XAML file, where you specify `x:Class` attribute, eg. `x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"`

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no need to rename the class when renaming the file. To make sure visual studio can still find the files it needs a clean and rebuild might be needed after renaming the file because the generated file, with the bindings between the window and the code-behind, might be cached with the wrong name.

Comment: @EmondErno Hmm right, I usually did that to keep things clean, but you are actually right. But I am guessing that it happens automatically, leaving x:Class attribute incorrect.

Comment: Of course! I stick to the one class per file and making their names identical. That is common practice and sense.

Comment: Renaming XAML file clears .cs file for some reason. I'm using Resharper addon.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that in both relevant files `Window1.xaml` and `Window1.xaml.cs` the partial Window1 class is renamed equally.
Also you should Clear the build (In VS-Menu 'Build'-> '*Clear Build*') and/or manually delete the "Obj" folder of the project. There are generated code files like `Application.g.cs` etc in the Obj folders that might refer to old entities, and then causes these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is to select the xaml file in the solutions folder. Rename it there.
This will rename both the xaml and xaml.cs file. It also will rename the class in the code behind

It will NOT rename the class in the xaml file. This is the very first line in your xaml file. You need to rename this manually.

You may need to adjust the namespace as wel for consistency. This may trigger other error messages.

Sometimes this behaves a bit nasty, because the compiler will generate code for the xaml file. If it does not compile and you get a lot of weird errors, do a rebuild for your project.